# Easy way to add standardUserDefaults to Crittercism error report metadata?

Tags: ios, crittercism

I could add them one by one using the Crittercism method

```
[Crittercism setValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key];
```

...but that is fragile when adding new settings and error prone. Can anybody suggest a better way to just add the entire settings dictionary to the user metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been thinking about adding an API call that lets you add the settings dictionary to metadata, would that work for you?

Rob
Critter Co-Founder

Comment: That would indeed work. I find that it's often some unexpected side effect of a combination of settings that makes my app crash. If I have to add the kv pairs manually, I'll add a setting in the future and forget to add it to the metadata for the user report :)